# Truffle Migrate Error: Could not find built Migrations contract: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, mac-osx

Running `truffle migrate` with valid contract code started causing this error for me:

```
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Using network 'development'.

Error: Could not find built Migrations contract: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at Object.lastCompletedMigration (/Users/joran/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-migrate/index.js:253:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by MacOS placing `.DS_Store` files inside the directories which truffle attempted to load as JSON.

Remove any `.DS_Store` files from your project:

```
find . -name '.DS_Store' -exec rm -r {} \;
```